# Constraint: Two type variables can be used with an operator

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the following function that compiles and runs successfully:

```
-- Linearly interpolates between two values. That is, it is a function which:
--   returns y1 when x = x1
--   returns y2 when x = x2
--   returns a value between y1 and y2 when x1 < x < x2
linearInterp x1 y1 x2 y2 x =
  (x - x1) * slope + y1
  where slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
```

I'd like to give it a type signature:

```
linearInterp :: a -> b -> a -> b -> a -> b
```

But, as expected, the type signature causes a compile error. That's because the compiler can't be sure it's possible to do arithmetic with arbitrary types `a` and `b`. E.g. it doesn't know you can divide `b` by `a`, as I do in my definition of `slope`.

Is there a way to write type constraints saying that "`a / b` is possible," "`a + b` is possible," etc? I've seen the `Mul`, `Div`, and `Sum` typeclasses. But they don't appear to tell the compiler anything about doing arithmetic on two *different* types.

In case you're wondering, this is important for me because I'm using the Dimensional package. It is indeed possible to do arithmetic on different types within that package. So you could, for example, call `linearInterp` where type `a` is `Length Float` and type `b` is `Velocity Float` .

Comment: What type is inferred for linearInterp? You can check with :t in ghci or with -fwarn-missing-signatures with ghc.

Comment: Actually, did it myself - see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I wrap your code in an import of the dimensional Prelude:

```
import Prelude ()
import Numeric.Units.Dimensional
import Numeric.Units.Dimensional.Prelude

linearInterp x1 y1 x2 y2 x =
  (x - x1) * slope + y1
  where slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
```

I get this type inferred:

```
linearInterp
  :: (Fractional a, Mul d1 d' d, Div d d1 d') =>
     Dimensional DQuantity d1 a
     -> Dimensional DQuantity d a
     -> Dimensional DQuantity d1 a
     -> Dimensional DQuantity d a
     -> Quantity d1 a
     -> Quantity d a
```

That seems like quite a reasonable type for the function if you do want that kind of generality.

The `Mul`, `Div` and `Sum` type classes do actually tell the compiler about doing arithmetic on different types, because they are *multi-parameter* classes: they each take *three* parameters representing the left argument type, the right argument type and the result type.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm wondering if I can add a type declaration to linearInterp, to ease reading and help diagnose programmer errors. I can't seem to find a type declaration that doesn't produce a compiler error. The error is always along the lines of "can't match a to b in the expression a / b"

Comment: You can add exactly the type that's inferred (perhaps rename the type variables to be more descriptive) - are you hoping for something simpler?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Thanks!